# Select statement with an And operator only used if a value is equals to something

Tags: mysql, sql

How do i make a an Select statement that haves an AND Operator that only is used if a value is equals to something.
So for example i got this statement

```
Select u.ID from xxx WHERE xxx
```

Then i got an And operator that only shall be used if a value is equals to something.
Thanks

Comment: What is the alternative to a value being equal to something?  I don't understand the question.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: yeah , your question is not clear

Comment: The alternative is, that there isn't any AND operator. And it just gets executed without the AND operator

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want this...

If `value` is `'extra'` use `WHERE xxx AND yyy` else use `WHERE xxx`

That's just boolean logic...

```
WHERE
   (value != 'extra' AND xxx)
   OR
   (value  = 'extra' AND xxx AND yyy)
```

That itself can reduce to...

```
WHERE
   xxx
   AND (value != 'extra' OR yyy)
```